# Laravel7 - Exclude directory via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-7

Good morning
I need to exlude a specific directory from the routing path of my Laravel 7 installation.

That's what I have on the server:

```
/var/www/myproject.local

/var/www/dir_to_exclude
```

I can also move `dir_to_exclude` inside Laravel root folder, if needed!

I found this `.htaccess` listing on line but it seems non to work!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^(dir_to_exclude) - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The host file on the server shows only one line

```
IP_ADDESS  myproject.local  myproject
```

The hostname shows simply "myproject"

So, why the `.htaccess` is ignored and Laravel keeps showing "404 not found" every time I try to access a file inside the excluded directory?

**EDIT**
I tried another solution, with different results. It still does not work :(
I removed the .htaccess I created inside the project root folder and I tried to modify the one inside /public folder like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Exclude directory from rewriting
RewriteRule ^dir_to_exclude($|/) - [L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I remember you my project structure, to be clear.

```
/var/www/myproject
|- dir_to_exclude
|-- info.php
|- public
|-- .htaccess
```

I call http://www.myproject.local/dir_to_exclude/info.php

This time I receive an Apache 404 error page... not the formatted Laravel one.
Well, it's not so good!

EDIT

This is the Virtual Host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/myproject>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject
    ServerName www.myproject.local
    ErrorLog /var/log/myproject.log

    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This issue is no more important. I solved using a symlink inside the /public folder. It fits my needs, after all.

Comment: I assume `/var/www` is the document root and the `.htaccess` file is located at `/var/www/.htaccess`?

Comment: Is your server configured to accept requests to `myproject.local`? What is the URL you are requesting? "why the .htaccess is ignored" - Is the `.htaccess` working to route your URLs?

Comment: @MrWhite - .htaccess works with the normal routing, and routes works fine even without it. Of course, the server respond to www.myproject.local (fake name...), but I reiceive a page 404 when I call www.myprojct.local/dir_to_exclude/info.php

I tried to put .htaccess in /var/www and also in /var/www/myproject, just to be sure...

Comment: "and routes works fine even without it" - HHhmm, but that's not possible, unless you have another `.htaccess` file (or directives in the server config)? Or your URLs include `index.php` (eg. `/index.php/some-route`)?

Comment: @MrWhite. No route includes index.php ...

Comment: What is the virtualhost config? What is the document root (ie. the setting of the `DocumentRoot` directive in the server config)?